# Метод get?

Tags: post, get, javascript

Есть вопрос.
У меня есть сайт, на сайте должны быть ссылочки на компанию, которая предоставила возможность 3Д-тура. В общем, идешь ты к нам, хочешь посмотреть что у нас, переходишь по ссылке, попадаешь на чужой сайт, в котором есть только возможность как бы бродить по фотографиям в режиме 3Д. Суть в том, что люди очень хотят, чтобы я сделала так, чтобы не было перехода на сторононний ресурс, чтобы в адресной строке отображался адрес нашего сайта.

Насколько я поняла, это делается чем-то типа метода GET, путем добавления скрипта, например, такого:

```
var parseQueryString = function (strQuery) {
var strSearch   = strQuery.substr(1),
    strPattern  = /([^=]+)=([^&]+)&?/ig,
    arrMatch    = strPattern.exec(strSearch),
    objRes      = {};
while (arrMatch != null) {
    objRes[arrMatch[1]] = arrMatch[2];
    arrMatch = strPattern.exec(strSearch);
}
return objRes;
```

};

или такого:

```
var parseQueryString = function (strQuery) {
var i,
    tmp     = [],
    tmp2    = [],
    objRes   = {};
if (strQuery != '') {
    tmp = (strQuery.substr(1)).split('&');
    for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i += 1) {
        tmp2 = tmp[i].split('=');
        if (tmp2[0]) {
            objRes[tmp2[0]] = tmp2[1];
        }
    }
}
return objRes;
};
```

Но с ними ничего не происходит вообще, плюс, не работает основной 3Д тур.
Постигать новое самостоятельно в таком темпе я не успеваю.
Подскажите, тут нужно какие-то значения менять?
Или, если знаете, где можно про это подробно почитать - киньте ссылку, пожалуйста.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: посмотрите исходный код, как вставлен 3д-тур на сайте той компании, и вставьте его себе на сайт (если, конечно, та компания не против).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте **iframe**

```
<iframe src="адрес к сайту"></iframe>
```

http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг кто-то будет искать, и ему подойдет, то вот, как я решила:

```
<script>
var parseQueryString = function (strQuery) {
    var strSearch   = strQuery.substr(1),
        strPattern  = /([^=]+)=([^&]+)&?/ig,
        arrMatch    = strPattern.exec(strSearch),
        objRes      = {};
    while (arrMatch != null) {
        objRes[arrMatch[1]] = arrMatch[2];
        arrMatch = strPattern.exec(strSearch);
    }
    return objRes;};

</script>
```

И вторая часть, она содержит как раз ссыль на сторонний сайт с туром.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loc = parseQueryString(window.location.search)['location'];
    if (loc==null) loc='zoldol-2';
    document.write(' <iframe width="100%" height="600" src="http://3dpanorama.spb.ru/3dtur'+'/'+ loc +'"></iframe>');
</script>
```

Причем задача у меня была специфическая в итоге.
Мне необходимо было вывести 2 окна (склоны и коттеджи) в общей странице тура, а с других страниц если была ссыль на тур, то нужно было, чтобы он показывал именно тот объект, с которого был совершен переход, но на общей странице тура. Короче, мы написали такую шляпу, сверху она. Причем все это ставится на странице общего тура, а с других страниц совершается переход путем изменения ссылки по такому типу:
`<a href="/3d-tour?location=` - константа в записи, а далее уже короткая ссылка непосредственный объект стороннего сайта, но при этом в поисковой строке всегда будет отображаться не тот сторонний сайт с туром, а наш. На самом деле все просто оказалось.

Comment: Или я не понял вопроса, или это БРЕД. Essle все правильно сказал. Если вам нужно показать 3Д тур с другого сайта на вашем сайте, нужен iframe и немного CSS кода.